# EOF в чтении файла по-символьно

Tags: c

Ситуация: допустим читаю файл(с русскими символами) по-символьно:

```
char ch = fgetc(file);
```

И пока не встречу EOF. И тут, в файле появляется символ 'я'. Как корректно считать? Программа на условие *EOF == 'я'* выдаёт истину.

Comment: Читайте не в `char`, а в `int` (так правильно)

Comment: @avp и затем просто int сравнить с EOF? Ну вообще да, Ритчи писал об этом..вроде бы.

Comment: И  Ричи писал и все остальные 100 раз тут об этом уже писали и в [man fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) сразу же пишут -- **`int`** `fgetc(FILE *stream);`

Comment: @avp премного Вам благодарен.

Comment: @avp это правильно, но может быть не достаточно в общем случае, если текст в utf-8, где `"я"` два байта занимает (текст можно построчно читать, чтобы внутри буквы чтение не рубить).

Comment: @jfs, да, для чтения именно символов в `utf-8` (или в другой многобайтной кодировке) `fgetc` не удобен, он в любом случае читает по одному байту.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, `fgetc` возвращает `unsigned char`, преобразованный к типу `int`. Поэтому и ожидать следует `int`. *Обычно* `EOF` имеет значение -1, потому что оно не должно совпадать ни с одним валидным значением, которое может вернуть `fgetc`. Так как `fgetc` возвращает `unsigned char`, преобразованный к типу `int`, то любое валидное значение не может быть отрицательным. При использовании типа `char` для приема результата вы даже не сможете верно принять валидные символы.

```
int symbol = fgetc(file);
```

**Примечание:** Также если вы используете `fgetc` для чтения символов, не входящих в ASCII (кириллица не входит), то следует учесть кодировку. Хотя это будет зависеть от того, что вы собираетесь делать с полученными данными.